# How to send and receive large data using Qt UDP socket?

Tags: qt, sockets, network-programming, udp

I want to use Qt UDP (not TCP) socket to transfer file.
So I write code like this:

Sender

```
QFile file1(QString::fromStdString(filedir));
QByteArray bytes;
file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in(&file1);
while (!in.atEnd()) {
    bytes = in.read(8192).toAscii();
    udpSocket.writeDatagram(bytes, QHostAddress(ip), port.toInt());
}
```

Receiver

```
udpSocket1.bind(ui->sendPort->text().toInt());
connect(&udpSocket1,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(listenfile()));

void Widget::listenfile() {
    QFile file("received.txt");
    file.resize(0);
    file.open(QIODevice::Append);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    do {
        QByteArray data;
        data.resize(udpSocket1.pendingDatagramSize());
        udpSocket1.readDatagram(data.data(),data.size());
        QString str=data.data();
        ui->textBrowser1->append(str);
        out << data;
    } while (udpSocket1.hasPendingDatagrams());
}
```

When I send small file, there is no problem.
However, if i want to send large file (> 8192 bytes), the receiver can only get the top 8KB data even tested on localhost.
If I decrease the size number in sender, such as 1024. The receiver still only gets the top 8KB data.
If I increase the size number in sender to X bytes (X > 8192). The receiver will get the top X Bytes data.

It seems like the minimum size of Qt UDP packet to transfer is 8192 bytes. The receiver always gets the first packet, but can not receive others.

I have little experience in Qt and network programming, so I don't know whether my conjecture is right or not. Can you tell me how to change these codes to support receiving packets after the first packet so I can transfer large data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging a long time and using Wireshark to capture packets. I think the reason for the issue is QUdpSocket itself. Like many other examples on the Internet, my code probably is right. But the QUdpSocket Class is not appropriate for transfering large data. Because when the slot function connected to readyRead() is executing, subsequent datagrams can not trigger it again until the function is done. So the sender must sleep a while after sent some data to wait the receiver's slot function.

The conclusion is QUdpSocket Class is not a reliable to transfer large data. I should use low level Socket APIs, customize some protocols and design multi-process/multi-thread architecture to solve the problem fundamentally. Of course using TCP Sockets is another choice.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue for some time and it really gives me cancer. After trying many different approaches with QUdpSocket and having quite a cancerous time, I've decided the same thing in the end: QUdpSocket is not fit for handling high-rate data flow. Low-level winsock udp threads tend to solve the issue better. But it's really, **really** sad. I wish Qt came up with a solution to this serious problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue probably comes from this line:

```
} while (udpSocket1.hasPendingDatagrams());
```

You're expecting the entire set of packets to be queued up and ready to be received at once, but it's more likely that some will be available and later more will.  So you need to listen to the socket longer than that and determine when the other side actually has finished sending data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you mean I should use another thread loop forever to handle datagrams, or some other simple ways? I think connecting the readyRead() signal to the listenfile() slot can listen to the socket forever. Because when the sender sends the second file, the receiver can also get the top datagram instead of ignoring. (Maybe I was wrong)

Comment: Right...  You need to call your reading code whenever the readyRead() signal is emitted.  The problem will be detecting when one file ends and another starts.  You could probably do that with magic bytes in front of the packet if need be.  IE, always put a 1 byte packet with value 0x00 in front of a packet when there is more coming, and a 0x01 in front of the packet when it's the last one so you know it's the end of the file and the next packet will be the start of the second file.  But remember to strip off that byte before saving :-)

Comment: This doesn't, however, sound like a job for UDP in the first place.  I'm not sure why you're forcing UDP when sending big files.  That's more what TCP is meant for.  And typically, you should send chunks in 1400 byte packets so UDP doesn't need to fragment.  And then, there is this whole issue of the fact that with UDP you may get packets lost and won't know it.  Or you may get a packet twice even!  Imagine what that'll do to your transferred files!   Again, you should really be using TCP.